# Android external events related stutter

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've been doing several opengl based games for Android recently, 
and there's one issue I can't find a way to get rid of.

When system starts some process in background (checking CDMA status, updating an app, or prerry much anything else), the game suffers a whole second stutter. Once in every few minutes. It was an annoying issue, until I started a breakout-style game, which is completely wrecked by that stutter (the ball teleport right through bricks).

It there a way to give the game activity priority over background processes, or pause all those background updates and installs while the game is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It there a way to give the game activity priority over background processes

The game activity already has "priority over background processes", to the extent that it can. Generally, background processes run in a class that limits their CPU utilization.

Note that Android's performance in this area has improved over the years. Your symptoms feel like what I would expect from an Android 1.5 device, for example.

> or pause all those background updates and installs while the game is running?

No, sorry.

Comment: I guess that answers my questions, but sadly leaves the problem.

Comment: I still have this same problem on Jellybean.